# Logo disappear in ubuntu

Tags: logo, statusbar

This is a picture of my status bar. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. This happens quite often. How can I resolve this?

[image]

This is what it should have been looked like.

[image]

Comment: Another picture showing its healthy state would help, so we could spot the difference, and thus understand the problem.

Comment: Not clear what logo you are referring to. Please [edit] your question with details of your version of Ubuntu

Comment: I have edited it. Thanks for the feedback.